# Hidden DOM element containing the message and to make it visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visibility

I need to show message "Please wait Processing" on click of Submit button using a hidden DOM element which contains the message and make it visible, but the message is not showing.

My html for the form and my validate function are given below.

```
<form name="siteSearchForm" method=post action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/servlet/visibilityController" onsubmit="javascript:return validate();on_load()">
    <td align="center" width="10%"><input type=submit name="siteSearchSubmit" value="SUBMIT" >&nbsp;<input type="RESET" name="clearTN" value="RESET"></td>
</form>
```

I tried the below code by calling `on_load` on form tag during `onsubmit` but it is not showing message

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function on_load(){
            var y = document.getElementById("txtHiddenUname");
            y.type= "text";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="txtHiddenUname" value="invalid input" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Becuase the return statement will exit the function call and nothing after it will run. You would need to add it BEFORE the return.

```
onsubmit="on_load(); return validate();"
```

or you can do

```
onsubmit="return validate() && on_load();"
```

but your on_load function needs to return true.

```
function on_load(){  return true; }
```

Also why are you using an input to display a message? Seems like you should be using a paragraph with display none/block. javascript: is not needed in event handlers, and on_load seems like it should be called on window load, not a form submission.

Comment: Thanks. Is there is any alternative way sorry I am not good in Javascript if possible please provide any code

Comment: Basically I need to display message to user it is "Processing Please wait" so I thought its easier way if you give any other input it will help me.

Comment: so have a `<p id="msg" style="display:none">FOO</p>` and `document.getElementById("msg").style.display = "block";`

Comment: I am bit confuse please tell me where to add is it like this <script type="text/javascript">
 function on_load(){
var y = document.getElementById("txtHiddenUname");
y.type= "text";
}
</script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> function on_load(){ var y = document.getElementById("msg").style.display = "block"; return true;} </script>  <p id="msg" style="display:none">Please wait Processing</p>  is it correct.I need to put return true please correct me

Comment: let me check this

Comment: Thanks working fine how to give the message in some bold type in <P

Comment: so add CSS to make it bold, or use a heading

Answer (score 0):

Also add the following line :

```
y.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply its useful